# Jenkins - Bitbucket Pull request builder is not working as expected

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, pull-request

I am trying to configure Jenkins for my project. My use-case is whenever someone raises the PR, the build should trigger automatically. So, after googling I found this plugin `Bitbucket Pull Request Builder` and I installed the plugin in Jenkins, Based on [this reference](https://github.com/nishio-dens/bitbucket-pullrequest-builder-plugin/blob/master/README.md), I added the configuration.

[image]

But the issue is, always Jenkins is trying to search the PR in a different location, i.e. `https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/rest/api/1.0/projects/m-suganthan/repos/test-jenkins/pull-requests/`, whereas PR is in this location, `https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/m-suganthan/test-jenkins/pullrequests`.

How can I tell the Jenkins to find the PR in the correct location?

Comment: Try putting just `https://bitbucket.org`—Jenkins is obviously trying to use the 1.0 API, and you can’t change that by adding 2.0 to the URL.

Comment: @DavisHerring, still it is not working, `bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucket.ApiClient send
WARNING: Response status: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found URI: https://bitbucket.org/rest/api/1.0/projects/m-suganthan/repos/test-jenkins/pull-requests/`

Comment: @DavisHerring more stacktrace, `bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucket.server.ServerApiClient getAllValues
WARNING: invalid response.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory.createJsonParser(JsonFactory.java:636)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1877)
        at bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucketpullrequestbuilder.bitbucket.ApiClient.parse(ApiClient.java:212)
        at `

Comment: I don’t know what else is wrong, but the 1.0 API is [going away](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/deprecation-notice-v1-apis/) soon anyway, so start by looking how to use the 2.0 version.

Comment: @DavisHerring, I will give a try then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved my issue using this plugin [Bitbucket Push And Pull Request Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Push+And+Pull+Request+Plugin).
Currently, this how my Jenkins configuration looks like.

**Update**: If you are having [Bitbucket-Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-plugin) installed in jenkins, then Bitbucket Push and Pull Request plugin won't work. Because the header `x-event-key=pullrequest:created` is not handled in former plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The BitBucket URL server (introduced in [PR 90](https://github.com/nishio-dens/bitbucket-pullrequest-builder-plugin/pull/90)) help should read:

> Fill that with your Bitbucket server URL if you do no use bitbucket.org service.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> http://localhost:7990/rest/api/2.0/projects/WORK
> ```

Make sure to reference your full URL repository in your case.

Also, check your credentials: the Basic Auth Username should be a login, not an email.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, I resolved my issue using `Bitbucket Push And Pull Request Plugin.`